# Why would AUC on a validation set increase while loss increases?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting, auc

[image: training loss]

[image: validation loss]

[image: validation AUC]

I'm training a deep learning model in PyTorch. The first two images I posted here make perfect sense as they are the classical idea of overfitting. The training loss keeps decreasing while the validation loss reaches a minimum and then starts to increase again. I assume this is where it would make sense to stop training the model.

What I don't understand is why the AUC on the validation set would keep increasing monotonically the entire time. Shouldn't it also reach a maximum and then start to decrease due to overfitting?

Comment: Is that logistic loss?

Comment: @AdamO Yes, to be more specific it's `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` from PyTorch library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that binary cross entropy and AUC are different metrics that measure different things. [This article](https://www.datamachines.io/blog/auc-vs-log-loss) gives a example of a data distribution where log-loss (similar to binary cross entropy) and AUC give different results.

The intuition is *what these metric care about*. AUC only cares about order. if $x_i$ is properly ordered below $x_j$ then AUC is happy. The exact predicted values for the two data points could change, but as long as they don't flip orders with other data points, the AUC remains the same.

Your loss function does care about values, not just order. So, in your case, what is most likely happening is the distributions of the two data (one for each classification case) sets are "shrinking" towards 0 & 1. This causes it to have bigger errors when it miss-classifies, because instead of giving point i a 70% chance of being in group 1, it gives it a 99% chance, as an example. This will destroy your loss. However, this only marginally effects your AUC.

So, your model appears to be getting better at classification in general if all you care about is correct classification. However, it's getting real cocky and overconfident, causing your loss to increase.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the gist of it. In my case I actually do care about classification, but it feels like a weird result to me, one that is not talked about often. I mean I would venture to say most deep learning problems are about classification yet are almost always optimizing loss...so why don't we hear more about this issue? Should we be optimizing for AUC instead of loss?

Comment: Great question. I suppose it depends on your exact use case. I think that because NNs have such a propensity to overfit, a metric that readily combated this became the industry standard. I also feel like AUC might might not play nice with gradient descent, since it treats the data ordinally more than continuously. It might get stuck in local minima more easily. No idea if that's true though. Either way, keeping an eye on AUC as you train is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah what's weird to me about this result is the fact that the AUC "accidentally" keeps increasing long after the optimum loss has been found. I'm not optimizing for AUC, so one would think it would just tag along with the validation loss. I'm at a loss (no pun) trying to understand that!

Comment: Well, that has to do with the train/validation split. AUC just isn't as sensitive to overfit since it isn't using as much information about probabilities.